# Include plugin in a wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress

How do i include the vafpress plugin in a wordpress theme without activation ?

files:

```
inc/plugins/vafpresscss/admin.css
inc/plugins/vafpressjs/admin.js
inc/plugins/vafpressviews/format-audio.php
inc/plugins/vafpressviews/format-gallery.php
inc/plugins/vafpressviews/format-link.php
inc/plugins/vafpressviews/format-quote.php
inc/plugins/vafpressviews/format-video.php
inc/plugins/vafpressviews/tabs.php
inc/plugins/vafpressvp-post-formats-ui.php
```

Comment: What do you mean with "without activation"? And here is a post about [How to Install a Wordpress for beginners](http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/step-by-step-guide-to-install-a-wordpress-plugin-for-beginners/)

Comment: how could you use the plugin without activating it in wordpress